# SQL get the date with the least profit made

Tags: sql, group-by, sql-order-by, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, min

Currently I am working on a query to get the Date with the least made profit. The table, that I am using for this is this one:

[image]

The query I came up with finds the date with the least made profit, but doesnt show the SUM of the amount made in that day:

```
SELECT MIN(PRICE*QUANTITY) AS UMSATZ, ORDER_DATE
FROM FACT_ORDER
GROUP BY ORDER_DATE
ORDER BY UMSATZ
LIMIT 1;
```

So the result is:
[image]

Which query could show the SUM amount of the profit made that day in addition (not with an additional column)? Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which query could show the SUM amount of the profit made that day in addition (not with an additional column)?

To get the total:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ORDER_DATE,
     SUM(PRICE*QUANTITY) OVER(PARTITION BY ORDER_DATE) AS UMSATZ 
FROM FACT_ORDER
QUALIFY (PRICE*QUANTITY) = MIN(PRICE*QUANTITY) OVER(PARTITION BY ORDER_DATE);
```

Comment: Thank you! I need to add, that I am using Snowflake -sorry. It gives me a Syntax Error for "PARTITION".

Comment: @telarewa It was supposed to be for Snowflake. There was a typo which is now fixed

Comment: Oh thats right, now it works - Thank you! I added a Order By and a LIMIT 1 to get only the right first row.

Comment: I just noticed that it does not give me the minimum value, but the maximum, as searched. Even though the MIN function is used, I can't get the minimum value out. Could you help me here out pls?

Comment: @telarewa I would need to get the CREATE TABLE with sample data that is not working to recreate your case.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with a self join.

```
select umsatz, a.order_date, sumUmsatz from (
    select 
    min(price*quantity) as umsatz, order_date
    from FACT_ORDER 
    group by datum order by min(price*quantity)asc
)a inner join (
    select sum(price*quantity) as sumUmsatz, order_date from 
    FACT_ORDER group by order_date
) b on a.order_date = b.order_date
where rownum = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried it and replaced where rownum =1 with LIMIT 1 to match the Snowflake SQL. But it gives me the following Error: SQL compilation error: ambiguous column name 'ORDER_DATE.

Comment: I edited the solution above.

Comment: Now it works just fine, thank you!